# Filtering coupled lists using zip and filter

Tags: python, filter, zip

I have a number of coupled lists x and y with the same number of values as shown below:

```
[(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(x3,y3),(x4,y4)]
```

where `x = [0,2,5,4,3...]`
and `y = [1,3,4,5,4...]`

The complete zipped list looks like `zipped = [([0,2,3,5,4],[4,3,4,6,5]),([0,2,6,5,4],[4,2,4,6,5]),([0,2,3,1,4],[4,3,2,6,5]),([0,2,4,5,4],[4,3,3,6,5])]`

My goal is to filter y values in lists `y1`, `y2`, `y3`, `y4` below a certain threshold `k`, and to remove the corresponding `x` values in lists `x1`, `x2`, `x3`, `x4`.

So far I tried the following

```
zipped = list(zip([x1,x2,x3,x4],[y1,y2,y3,y4]))

for data in zipped:
 
    filtered = filter(lambda z: z[1]<k, data)
```

Unfortunately, when I print "filtered", I am not getting the output I want. I want to get the updated zipped list but without the `y` values below threshold `k` and without the corresponding `x` values.

Any ideas? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
data = [([0,2,3,5,4],[4,3,4,6,5]),([0,2,6,5,4],[4,2,4,6,5]),([0,2,3,1,4],[4,3,2,6,5]),([0,2,4,5,4],[4,3,3,6,5])]

k = 4

filtered_data = []
for data in l:
    filtered = list(filter(lambda pair: pair[1] < k, zip(*data)))
    filtered_data.append(filtered)


# rebuild the original input format
print(list(list(zip(*i)) for i in filtered_data))
```

Comment: Hi cards, I have tried this, however, I get the error saying "'<' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'float'". My zipped list looks like this: [([0,2,3,5,4],[4,3,4,6,5]),([0,2,6,5,4],[4,2,4,6,5]),([0,2,3,1,4],[4,3,2,6,5]),([0,2,4,5,4],[4,3,3,6,5])]

Comment: Hi cards, yes, I need to filter globally (along each y-s in each pair). For example, if my threshold for y is >=2, I would expect to get:  [([0,2,3,5,4],[4,3,4,6,5]),([0,6,5,4],[4,4,6,5]),([0,2,1,4],[4,3,6,5]),([0,2,4,5,4],[4,3,3,6,5])]

Comment: what do you expect as output? a flat array or a list of tuples?

Comment: a zipped list of lists, similar to input just without the values below threshold for y and the corresponding values for x